# Direct3D11 Effects: How do I programmatically get the name of a vertex shader function?

Tags: c#, vertex-shader, direct3d11

I am writing an application w/Direct3D11. I want to programmatically retrieve the name of each vertex shader found within a given technique and pass. Here is pseudocode:

```
Effect fx = GetEffect();

for( int i = 0; i < fx.Description.TechniqueCount; ++i )
{
    EffectTechnique tech = fx.GetTechnique();
    for( int j = 0; j < tech.Description.PassCount; ++j )
    {
        EffectPass pass = tech.GetPass(j);

        // VERTEX SHADER NAME
        string vertexShaderName = ...
    }
}
```

How do I get the name of each vertex shader function?

Comment: Why do you need to? Is this perhaps for a subroutine?

Comment: I think you're out of luck, compiled shader programs don't store the subprogram names, only the technique names (i think, it has been a lot since I did DX)

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm writing an IDirect3D11Effect wrapper class. I want to programmatically create an input layout for each function found within an effect...This way I won't have to update the effect class every time I update the effect file

Comment: BTW, which version of Effects for Direct3D 11 are you using? The legacy DirectX SDK version or the latest one from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11).

Comment: I'm using the Direct3D 11 SDK

Comment: Will an input layout created for one shader work for a different shader as long as their signatures match?